# В чем разница между left join и right join?

Tags: sql

Прочитал теорию, попробовал.

LEFT JOIN
Выбирает из первой таблицы все записи и присоединяет к ним записи из второй таблицы, по указанным для сравнения колонкам. Если не находит, то присоединяет null.

RIGHT JOIN
Аналогично LEFT JOIN но наоборот - выбирает из второй таблицы все записи и присоединяет к ним записи из первой таблицы, по указанным для сравнения колонкам. Если не находит, то присоединяет null.

Из определений, согласно формальной логике, следует вывод, что достаточно одного джоина, например левого.

Эти запросы выведут абсолютно одинаковые таблицы. Разница лишь в следовании полей, что в запросах не имеет никакого значения.

```
SELECT * FROM job LEFT JOIN persons ON persons.job_title = job.job_title; 
SELECT * FROM persons RIGHT JOIN job ON persons.job_title = job.job_title;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**В чем разница между left join и right join?**

Comment: ```a LEFT JOIN b``` == ```b RIGHT JOIN a```. *В чем разница между left join и right join?* Ни в чём. Единственная зримая разница - при LEFT JOIN порядок сканирования таблиц соответствует тексту запроса, а при RIGHT JOIN нет.

Comment: *Эти запросы выведут абсолютно одинаковые таблицы. Разница лишь в следовании полей, что в запросах не имеет никакого значения.* Это потому что используется `SELECT *`, что на самом деле bad practice. Напиши список конкретных полей конкретных таблиц  - и от этой разницы ничего не останется.

Comment: @Akina SELECT * использован для примера. Список конкретных полей не повлияет на результат, просто останутся указанные поля в таблице.

SELECT persons.name, job.job_title, job.salary  FROM persons RIGHT JOIN job ON persons.job_title = job.job_title;

SELECT persons.name, job.job_title, job.salary  FROM job RIGHT JOIN persons ON persons.job_title = job.job_title;

Таблицы аналогичны вышеприведенным. Они одинаковы, в них присутствуют указанные поля, только порядок полей (столбцов) разный.

Comment: *Список конкретных полей не повлияет на результат* Да щазз.. если перечислены конкретные поля, то выходной набор будет точно соответствовать указанному порядку, и никакого "Разница лишь в следовании полей" не будет.

Comment: Если у вас длинный развесистый запрос, то не всегда вы можете расположить в этом запросе левую и правую часть запроса в определённом порядке, поэтому нужны оба варианта. Но в целом обычно просто используют `LEFT JOIN`, потому что он просто интуитивно человеку как-то более понятен. А вообще я до сих пор не могу привыкнуть к тому, что слово `OUTER` сократили, приходится лишний раз думать, что это на самом деле `OUTER JOIN`. )